# FMX shape components does not correctly displayed on the Android platform

Tags: android, delphi, graphics, firemonkey

As you can see, the shape components normal display on Windows platform, very smooth (including lines, corners and gradient effect).

[image]

But on the Android platform, you get another unacceptable results: lines are no longer smooth, corners cannot been closed, gradients become fully black.

[image]

**How does that happen? And How to fix it?**

Here is the .fmx file content:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object RoundRect1: TRoundRect
    Position.X = 40.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 16.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 153.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 65.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Stroke.Color = claMediumslateblue
    Stroke.Thickness = 8.000000000000000000
  end
  object Pie1: TPie
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 96.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 153.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 129.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Stroke.Color = claChocolate
    Stroke.Thickness = 8.000000000000000000
    EndAngle = -90.000000000000000000
  end
  object Arc1: TArc
    Position.X = 48.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 224.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 169.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Stroke.Color = claDeeppink
    Stroke.Thickness = 10.000000000000000000
    StartAngle = 30.000000000000000000
    EndAngle = 180.000000000000000000
  end
  object Arc2: TArc
    Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 184.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 233.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 233.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Stroke.Kind = Gradient
    Stroke.Gradient.Points = <
      item
        Color = xFF297E72
        Offset = 0.000000000000000000
      end
      item
        Color = xFFA6F2BD
        Offset = 1.000000000000000000
      end>
    Stroke.Gradient.StartPosition.X = 0.500000000000000000
    Stroke.Gradient.StartPosition.Y = 1.000000000000000000
    Stroke.Gradient.StopPosition.X = 0.499999970197677600
    Stroke.Gradient.StopPosition.Y = 0.000000000000000000
    Stroke.Thickness = 20.000000000000000000
    Stroke.Cap = Round
    EndAngle = -90.000000000000000000
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe in the docs it says that gradients on Strokes (lines) do not work on anything but the Windows 2D rendering. I wasn't able to find where it says that however. If you want the Windows version to use 3D you can do:

```
initialization
FMX.Types.GlobalUseGPUCanvas := True;
```

You can also turn on multisampling by [overriding the rendering parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Overriding_OpenGL_Rendering_Parameters). Lastly you can use a [native Android component](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiandroid/) for native drawing if you need it.

Comment: Do you need the objects to change at runtime? As in you're doing something with drawing? If not there are ways to cache the Windows look to a bitmap.

Comment: Yes, I need to change those objects at runtime.